# For some reason this PHP doesn't take place after submitting a form

Tags: forms, if-statement

I have the following HTML +javascript form:

```
<script>
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
var form = document.getElementById("myform");
var link = document.getElementById("submit-link");
link.addEventListener("click", function(event) {

    event.preventDefault();
    form.submit();

}, false);
}, false);
</script>

<form action="" method="post" id="myform">
<a id="submit-link" href="http://www.google.com">Submit</a>
</form>
```

The following CSS code for design:

```
.ssd {
border: none;
background-color: transparent;
padding: 0;
cursor: pointer;
font-size:89%;
display:inline;
text-decoration: underline; 
color: #00c;  
}
```

And this PHP code:

```
if(isset($_POST['myform'])){
$xmla = new SimpleXMLElement('passwords/' . views . '.xml', 0, true);
$plus = $xmla->goodx;
$result = $plus + 1;
$xmla->goodx = $result;
$xmla->asXML('passwords/' . views . '.xml');


}
```

Now, Every time that the user clicks on the value "Click", the XML file is supposed to be updated with data, and then redirect to google.com. It works, but when the user places his mouse over the link, he sees the URL of my site, and not google's. any ideas how to solve it?

Comment: `action="http://google.com"` submits the form to google...

Comment: yes, that is what I am trying to do, to monitor the clicks of users and to see how many time they go to google(my xml file tells me how many time they clicked).

Comment: In that case you should submit the form to YOUR page, count the click and then redirect to google

Comment: Check my code again, I did exactly what you said but it doesnt work.

Answer (score 1):

Use action="" and redirect to the right google.com page.
Look at the google.com URL to know how it works.

**Edit:**

To see the link in each browser, you will need to use a link and post the form with JavaScript:

```
<script>
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    var form = document.getElementById("myform");
    var link = document.getElementById("submit-link");
    link.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        form.submit();
    }, false);
}, false);
</script>

<form action="" method="post" id="myform">
    <a id="submit-link" href="http://www.google.com">Submit</a>
</form>
```

This way, the user will see the google link and it will post to your PHP script.

Comment: Update: it doesn't always work for some reason, sometimes it updates the XML and sometimes it doesn't. Sometimes when I click on the link, it redirectes me to the current page instead of google, and on those cases only it works, and sometimes it redirectes me to google, and in those cases it doesnt update the XML. –

Comment: This code should always redirect to the current page. You have to redirect on server side. I updated the submit handler to see if there is any difference. By the way, on which web browser are you testing? This code works on Firefox, Opera and Chromium.

Comment: It works, but in FireFox and Chrome you can't see the link when you place your mouse over the form.

Comment: But how can I use it in order to run my PHP code? I can't activate PHP with JAVA...

Comment: Look at the form action. It is empty, meaning the form submits to the same page. The form is submitted with JavaScript, then your PHP script will be executed (because the form has been submitted) and you redirect the user to Google.

Comment: But it doesn't update the XML file. I updated my code to show you what I did exactly. thank you VERY much for help btw.

Comment: This condition will always be false: `if(isset($_POST['myform'])){` because there is no form element named myform. It is why the PHP code does not get executed. If you have trouble with debugging the PHP code, remove the redirect to Google (to see what PHP prints) and prints some text with PHP on the code to see what's going on. This way, you could see if the PHP scripts is executed and if the code in the condition is executed. You will have to do some tests like this to get your code working.

Comment: I didn't manage to do that. /: but thanks your help though buddy, you really tried and I appreciate you